# Exporting Vue components as npm module

Tags: vuejs2

I have problem to make Vue component export work properly.
I can export the component successfully and when I try to import it in different project I get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
```

This is the Webpack config that I use for export:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const utils = require('./utils');

function resolve(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

var config = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname + '/../src/components/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/../dist/timer-comp/'),
    filename: 'timer-component.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.vue', '.js', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: false
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      sourceMap: false,
      mangle: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

This is the code that I use to export the components:

```
import TimerComponent from './timer-component';

export {
  TimerComponent,
};
```

And finally the component code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="time">{{time}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'TimerComponent',
    data() {
      return {
        time: ''
      };
    },
    created() {
      setInterval(() => {
        let now = new Date();
        this.time = now.getHours() + " : " + now.getMinutes() + " : " + now.getSeconds();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Does someone have a clue why I get this error Failed to mount component ?

by the way this is how I call the component in a different project:

```
import TimerComponent from 'timer-comp';
```

It seems that the issue is caused by the build somehow, but I can't figure out what could be the exact problem.

Comment: is your vuejs project running without any errors in development mode?

Comment: yes no errors in development mode as the component is simple clock it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add output property in production webpack config file:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/../dist/timer-comp/'),
  filename: 'timer-component.js',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  libraryExport: 'default',
  library: 'TimerComponent',
  umdNamedDefine: true
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
I already used library and libraryTarget and with them I got same output.
I added also now libraryExport: 'default' but now I got Unknown custom element. So at least the message has changed.
Do you have any idea why it does not recognizes the component ?

Comment: The code is pasted at the top.

import TimerComponent from './timer-component';

export {
  TimerComponent,
};

Comment: ok. you use TimerComponent as a component just upload 'src' in **npm**

, if you want to use as a library [see](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)

Comment: Thanks Volodymyr, uploading just the src seems to be working fine.